# Azure Function with AD auth results in 401 Unauthorized when using Bearer tokens

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have a very simple Azure function in C# for which I've setup Azure AD Auth. I've just used the Express settings to create an App registration in the Function configuration.

```
public static class IsAuthenticated
{
    [FunctionName("IsAuthenticated")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "options", Route = null)]
        HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult("You are " + req.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    }
}
```

When I access the function in my browser everything works as expected (if not logged in I have to login and get redirected to my API). But if I try to access my function anywhere a Bearer token is needed I get an `401 Unauthorized` error. Even weirder I also can't execute the function in the Azure Portal.

[image]

But the token was aquired without a problem and added to the request:

[image]

I've tried a few different things to solve this problem. First I thought maybe it's a CORS problem (since I've also had a few of those) and just set CORS to accept *, but nothing changed.

Then I've added my API login endpoints to the redirect and tried setting the implicit grant to also accept Access tokens, it's still not working.

[image]

Is there anything I've overlooked? Shouldn't the App registration express config just work with azure functions?

**EDIT:**

Putting the URL to my function app in the redirects as suggested by [@thomas-schreiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55227490/503059) didn't change anything (I've tried the config in the screenshot and also just putting each of those values on it's own).

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I've now also tried to aquire an Bearer token the manual way [with Postman](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/05/23/using-postman-to-call-the-microsoft-graph-api-using-authorization-code-flow/), but I still run into a 401 when calling my API.

Comment: which client are you using to attain and call the azure function?

Comment: My real client app is an angular application with @azure/msal-angular, but there I get the same error as if I just execute the function in the Azure portal (which I'm using in the screenshots). I actually get a Bearer token and it's added to the request, but then I get the 401 Unauthorized error

Comment: I faced the issue simply since the code I provided in query string has problem whoever run into this can check that out first.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**UPDATE 2020-05-12:** According to [ambrose-leung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2205372/ambrose-leung)'s answer [further below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719747/503059) you can now add a custom issuer URL which should potentially enable you to use v2 tokens. I haven't tried this myself, but maybe this will provide useful for someone in the future. (If his answer helped you please give him an upvote and maybe leave a comment )

---

This took forever to figure out, and there is very little information about this in the offical documentations.

But it turns out the problem was/is that Azure Functions don't support Bearer tokens generated by the oauth2/v2.0/ Azure API. Since the portal uses those (if your AD supports them) you are out of luck to be able to run the function in there.

This also explains why my postman requests didn't work, because I was also using the v2 api. After switching to v1 I could access my API (Postman doesn't allow you to add a resource_id when you use the integrated auth feature, so I had to switch to handling everything manually).

After that came the realisation that you can't use MSAL either if you are writing a JS client (Angular in my case). So one alternative is ADAL, where the Angular implementation looks kind of awkward. So I decided to use angular-oauth2-oidc which took another hour of tinkering to get it to play nicely with Azure AD.

But after all that I can finally access my API.

I really don't understand why you wouldn't allow users to access Azure Function Apps with Azure AD v2 tokens, but at least this should be so much better documented. But whatever, I can finally go to sleep.

**EDIT:** After I opend an issue for this, they added a note that v2 isn't supported by Azure Functions, hopefully making life easier for other people.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad

Comment: Yeah thanks who ever downvoted my answer, which actually solved my problem, you are a really big guy 

Comment: Where can you switch to the v1 endpoint...? I'm trying to use AAD B2C and getting the same behaviour. Thanks

Comment: Actually ignore that, I've checked my token and it says 1.0 in the ver claim so I guess my issue is something different. This is painful....

Comment: FWIW, finally got it working by going through all the claims in the JWT and seeing what the mismatches were, turned out to be a difference in the issuer claim on my login flow vs on the auth settings on the function app.

Answer (score 12):

I managed to get it working through postman using following configuration.
Important lesson was setting in "Allowed token audiences" and "resource" name used in postman to acquire token should be same in this case. I used the same code provided here in question. in this case app registered in Azure AD is a client and resource as well. configuration and testing through postman as follows

[image]

Acquire token in postman

[image]

Calling azure function using Postman .. Authorization header with bearer token

[image]

Comment: I've already found an answer to my problem but still thanks for your reply. Your answer would have actually helped me to get to an answer, because I would have noticed the difference between v1 and v2 earlier. But sadly it was about a day to late 

Comment: Why do you say that oauth2 is not working for Azure functions. Didn’t I acquire token using OAuth2

Comment: The problem isn't oauth2 but that Microsoft has two versions of their oauth2 API (/oauth2 vs /oauth2/v2.0) which are slightly different and to the best of my knowledge respectively use Azure AD v1 and v2.

Comment: Is it Possible to Pass client_secret and Client_id in Request headers?

Comment: As for today, v2.0 is currently supported

Answer (score 6):

You can now use v2.0 tokens!

Instead of choosing 'Express' when you configure AAD, you have to choose 'Advance' and add the /v2.0 part at the end of the URL.

[image: Choose Advanced]

This is the code that I use in my console app to present the user with a login prompt, then take the bearer token for use with the Azure Function.

```cs
string[] scopes = new string[] { "profile", "email", "openid" };
string ClientId = [clientId of Azure Function];
string Tenant = [tenantId];
string Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
var _clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
    .WithAuthority($"{Instance}{Tenant}")
    .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
    .Build();
var accounts = _clientApp.GetAccountsAsync().Result;

var authResult = _clientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
            .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
            .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
            .ExecuteAsync().Result;
var bearerTokenForAzureFunction = authResult.IdToken;
```

Comment: Thanks for this information, I haven't tried this myself yet so I can't confirm if this would solve my original problem. But it looks promising and I've added a link to your answer with your name to my original answer so people will know about this possibility in the future ;)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.  My test was that I saw my email address returned by my Azure Function when I used `req.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: Works beautifully!

Answer (score 5):

When setting up your Active Directory authentication on your Function App, set management mode to advanced and fill in the Client ID and Issuer URL as required (and the client secret if necessary).

Importantly, under the **Allowed Token Audiences**, enter the **Application ID URI**. This can be found in your registered App Registration (in your AD) under the **Expose an API** option.

This is what I was missing to get authentication working on my Function App. Before I added that token audience, I would always get a 401 with a valid access token.

This [Azure active directory - Allow token audiences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640158/azure-active-directory-allow-token-audiences) helped me get my answer but it took me a while to realise what it was referring to. Remember, it's the Application ID URI that can be found within your App Registration.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I spent hours today over this. My Application ID URI was also incorrect. In my function app the Allowed Token Audiences was set to the url of the function app.  The Application ID URL was something else entirely! :)

Comment: Thank you! For me, this was the solution. I also failed to set the **Allowed Token Audience**, after adding the token audience the authenticated request with bearer token works.

Answer (score 2):

If you are banging your head against the wall like myself and the original poster, it may be that you are allowing users to sign in from "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)."

Note that as of May 2021, v2.0 works perfectly. If you use https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token to get a token with Postman (as described above), you will get a valid token that you can use to auth your AZ Function with.

With that said, IF a **user is signed in via a personal account or an account not within your AAD**, the token call made by MSAL is requested with the default Microsoft tenant id, NOT your tenant id.

THIS is why I was unable to auth my function. If you are logged in with a user in your tenant's AAD, MSAL is amazing and easy to use and everything will work as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In the AAD app itself, go to Settings -> Reply URLs and verify that the url of the Function App is in the list, which has the following format: `https://mycoolapp.azurewebsites.net`. If it isn't, then add it.

If you use slots, you have to add it for both slots.

Comment: The auth path was already configured there by the Express setup. I've tried only putting my function url in there and also the configuration in my edit of my question, but it still doesn't work sadly :/ Can you think about anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: Actually no. :/ My other idea was the AuthorizationLevel, but that is already set to Anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i can think of right now is Allowed Audience.

Go to Your Active directory settings and click Advance. Under **Allowed Token Audience** 
Add your exact function url. It might already be there with call back url but Simply replace it with only function base url without any call back as mentioned in the picture.

Make sure when you press ok , you also save your Authentication / Authorization setting to take effect and try again after 1min or so.  I tested using PostMan and passing bearer token and it works !

[image]

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work either. Are there any special API permissions needed (app registration)? By default only `User.Read` is active.

Comment: are you using client id and secret key from  azure AD app registration ? or can you please how you are generating bearer token ?

Comment: I'm using MSAL for which you shouldn't use the client secrent, only the client id

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the exact same issue today. The issue turned out to be the resource id that I was passing when requesting the access token.

For example, initially I was requesting a token like this, using the function URL as the resource id:

```
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://myfunction.azurewebsites.net", "myClientAppIdGUID", new Uri("https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf"), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.SelectAccount)).Result;
```

While this returned an access token, I was receiving a 401 unauthorized when using the access token to call my function api.

I changed my code to pass my function apps App Id as the resource:

```
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("myFunctionAppIdGUID", "myClientAppIdGUID", new Uri("https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf"), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.SelectAccount)).Result;
```

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was solved when I added the scope: `[clientId]/.default`
per [this article](https://lionadi.wordpress.com/2020/04/03/azure-ad-and-azure-functions-authentication-401-problems-with-access-tokens/)