# Azure Functions secured with Azure AD - Getting HTTP 401 when calling from native app

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-functions

My goal is to secure my Azure Functions with Azure AD and call them from a WPF application.

I have an Azure Function with the following definition :

```
public IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
        HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log,
        ExecutionContext context,
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
```

I registered an Azure AD App and configured the settings for Native App Authentication :

[image: Azure AD App Registration Settings]

I configured my app in the "Expose an API" bladd
[image: Expose an API]

I also added an API Permissions

[image: API Permission]

I associated my app in my Azure Functions App in the Authentication / Authorization blade.

[image: Azure Functions Authorization Settings]

I am getting a token from Azure AD like this in a WPF app (using the Microsoft.Identity.Client library)

```
            string applicationID = "***"; // My AppID Guid
            PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(applicationID)
                .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
                .Build();

            var listScopes = new List<string>
            {
                //"user.read" - Removed based on @tony-yu recommendation
                $"api://{applicationID}/MyScope"
            };

            var authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(listScopes)
                                      .ExecuteAsync();

            var myToken = authResult.AccessToken;
```

I can authenticate without any problem and I am successfully getting a token but whenever I call my function and I provide my token in the Authorization header (Authorization = Bearer ****), I get :

**401 - You do not have permission to view this directory or page.**

Here's how I call it (Postman) :

[image]

Here is the WWW-Authenticate header content when the call returns

[image: www-authentication]

When I check the token I got, it seems legit

[image: Token]

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally made it work thanks to this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719747/344438) here by [ambrose-leung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2205372/ambrose-leung)

Answer (score 0):

The scope is not correct. As you want to access your function which is protected by ad, you need to use

```
var listScopes = new List<string>
            {
                "{applicationID}/.default"
            };
```

instead.

`user.read` is the permission for Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: it doesn't work I still get the 401 unauthorized after changing the scopes

Comment: @alexbf How did you call the function? Will the function url work in the browser?

Comment: I call my function from Postman (I added some details in the post). The function will not work from a browser as it is configured to be called from a NativeApp