# Azure Functions diagnose http 401

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions that I secured with Azure AD Authentication.

I am in a WPF app and I use the MSAL library to get a token. I am able to get a JWT token with a specific scope for my function from Microsoft authentication service. The token seems legit as I can open it in sites like https://jwt.io/. The info in the token seems good at first sight.

When I use the token to call the function I get a 401 - Unauthorized error.

My problem is that I have no idea what is wrong with my token.

How can I get more info from the 401 error in an Azure Functions? I couldn't find advanced logs anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the problem was with the token version. V1 vs V2.

Thanks to this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719747/344438) here by [ambrose-leung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2205372/ambrose-leung)